# Apache Drill: Reserved word "user" as one of the column names in json data file

Tags: json, keyword, apache-drill

I am querying a nested json file, the structure looks something like as follows

```
{"user_id":1234,
 "text":"example text"
 "first_nested":{
                 "field1":"dummy string 1",
                 "field2":"dummy string 2"
                },
  "user":{ 
           "field3":"dummy string 3",
           "field4":"dummy string 4"
          },
  "last":1}
```

I have a nested json structure named "user", and when query the following:

```
SELECT tbl.user AS us FROM dfs.`/filepath/trial.json` as tbl WHERE user_id=221
```

or

```
SELECT tbl.user.field1 AS us FROM dfs.`/filepath/trial.json` as tbl WHERE tbl.user_id=221
```

I get the following error:

```
UserRemoteException: PARSE ERROR: Encountered ". user" at line 1, column 11. Was expecting one of: "FROM" ... "," ... "AS" ... ... ... ... ... ... "." ... "NOT" ... "IN" ... "BETWEEN" ... "LIKE" ... "SIMILAR" ... "=" ... ">" ... "<" ... "<=" ... ">=" ... "<>" ... "+" ... "-" ... "*" ... "/" ... "||" ... "AND" ... "OR" ... "IS" ..
```

and when I simply use `user` with dereferencing with tbl. , the query return the name of the user who owns the current drill profile.

I can't change the name of the column from this json file, how do I get around this ?

Comment: *and when I simply use "user" without dereferencing with tbl.

Answer (score 2):

I looked this up in the docs. Use backticks for reserved words.

> Because the column alias contains the special space character, also enclose the alias in back ticks, as shown in the following example

From https://drill.apache.org/docs/lexical-structure/

In your case:

```
SELECT tbl.`user`.field1 AS us FROM ...
```